# How can I disable TinyMCE from stripping/modifying my HTML in Joomla?

Tags: configuration, joomla, tinymce

I've got a site running Joomla with TinyMCE set as the editor. One of the sites editors is now trying to embed a media player into an article but TinyMCE keeps messing up the HTML.

I've tried setting the Extended Valid Elements, in the plugin config, to `*[*]` to allow anything and everything but it's not working.

What I'd like is to disable the code stripping "feature" from TinyMCE all together. I don't want it trying to validate my HTML or anything like that.

How can I disable the code stripping?

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you can turn off all of the editors in Joomla:

Go to: extensions (Should be on the top tab control)
Click: Plug-in Manager.
This will take you to a list of all of Joomla's plugins.
Disable any plugins that start with "-editor".

This should leave you with plain-text editor which edits and saves Html without regard for what's in it. If you can find a better solution, use that but this worked when everything else failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

@dave: Here is the way you can stop the HTML striping: http://dijoomla.blogspot.com/2009/02/turn-off-tinymce-cleanup-code.html .

But it's recommended that you shouldn't do that, since the striping feature is for preventing exploits. Instead, you can consider using a tinymce plugin, such as [Media](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3amedia).

Comment: I'm not worried about exploits. I trust the few people, that have access to edit articles, won't be writing any naughty HTML. I couldn't find any reference to `mambots` but, according to Google, mambots was renamed to `plugins` in Joomla 1.5 So, I set the `code cleanup` option to `no` in the TinyMCE plugin manager. However, the HTML is still getting messed up in the article.

Comment: Solved it. The `code cleanup on startup` is off and `code cleanup on save` is set to Always. Seems to do the job.

Comment: @dave: I don't know which version of Joomla you are using, but is there other config option, like "cleanup at start" or "code cleanup on saving"?

Comment: @dave: it seems I miss your last comment. Glad that you find it

Answer (score 0):

```
Note:This works in 2.5 using JCE Editor (not sure 1.5)
```

Go to ...administrator>Global Configuration>Text Filters...
Now set no filtering on those permission levels you choose. Not your public levels to protect security. I can do this after updating to JCE and dropping TinyMCE.

I use the free JCE editor (under Components tab once installed), you can customize it much better with many added features OR un-customize it as needed many times.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 2.5, go to `plug-in manager > Editor - TinyMCE`. 
In the basic options, juste remove `iframe` from the Prohibited Elements.